Flutter get same behavour with PopScope as with deprecated WillPopScope
My app page has 3 ways of navigating

Pressing the save button -> Data gets saved to the database.
Pressing the delete button -> Temporarily stored data is deleted.
Pressing the close button or natively navigating back (back button or slide) -> Temporarily data is updated.

In all 3 cases, some code is executed and the page is popped.
With the old WillPopScope, onWillPop was only called when natively navigation back. In that case, I would execute scenario 3. The new PopScope.onPopInvoked is invoked every time the page is popped, no matter how it was popped. So I don't know which scenario should be triggered.
Is there a way to get the old behaviour back and only detect the native back navigation?
